# Is it possible to pack multiple scripts by pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to bundle two python scripts with pyinstaller so there is only one pyd "environment" and multiple executables (.exe in my case).

script1.py

```py
print("hello")
```

script2.py

```py
print("bye")
```

running `pyinstaller script1.py script2.py` creates folder `dist/script1` which contains `_internal` with `.pyd` files and `script1.exe`.

I want the `script2.exe` to be also available.

If I run `pyinstaller script1.py` and `pyinstaller script2.py` separately, I got two folders in `dist` and two `_internal` subfolders.

Is it possible to combine the calls so I have only one `_internal` and two `.exe`?